# Dynamic rate limiter to avoid db throttling

Tags: java, performance, rate-limiting

We have a service which have one singular API (deals with a single entity) ,avg latency=400ms and one batch api which deals with around 2000 entities in a single call[latency=200s]. Both api reads and write into db tables. The volume handled by both the apis is very different. The singular api has a well defined pattern which has daily maxima and minima at increases and decreases at a contant rate. The ddb tables are able to handle this traffic very well. The problem comes when the bulk api start receiving volume for around 2-3 hours daily and handles 20 times more entities per second as compared to the other api. This has impact on write/read of the db tables which are unable to auto-scale at such a brisk rate. .

We are thinking of options like rate limiting to achieve tune our traffic to adhere to the db auto scaling. We don't want to have a fixed rate beacuse that would impact our client's SLA (operator facing tool). Is there a way to have dynamic rate limits which can scale as per current traffic and would allow db enough time to auto scale?

Comment: Does your Bulk API produce any sensitive response so the clients of this API have to wait unitil request is processed and response is returned? If no, then yet another option is to use Kafka - you send everything that comes via Bulk API to Kafka topic, then asynchrously read from that topic and process each bulk of entities one by one, as before. In this case Kafka would work as persistent queue from where you can read at desired rate (depending on the number of consumers). Thus you will don't have to apply limitations on your API.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and have a look over the solution being provided by [Netflix Concurrency Limits](https://github.com/Netflix/concurrency-limits)

And the more detail about the same can be found in this wonderful article [Performance Underload](https://medium.com/@NetflixTechBlog/performance-under-load-3e6fa9a60581)